# Adding List Members As a Value To Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I couldn't find any similar codes so i need your help on my junior question. I summarize the code as follows:

```
A=[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}]
L=['x', 'y']

B=[]
for i in A:
    for j in L:
        i["c"]=j
        B.append(i)

print(B)
```

The output is:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'y'}, {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'y'}]
```

What i need is:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'x'}, {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': 'y'}]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Cakma, welcome to SO :) Please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the dictionary in your loop, or else it appends the same dictionary twice.

Under the hood, it uses a pointer to the original dictionary. Which means you are editing the same dictionary. When you add it, you are editing the original object, and then saying "This same object is in the list twice.

Here is the code...

```
import copy

A=[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}]
L=['x', 'y']

B=[]
for i in A:
    for j in L:
        i2 = copy.deepcopy(i)
        i2["c"]=j
        B.append(i2)

print(B)
```

Answer (score 3):

A more concise, though less readable version:

```
A = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}]
L = ['x', 'y']

B = [ {**z, 'c': j } for j in L for z in A ]
```

Comment: This is the way it should be done in practice; however, it would likely be confusing to the poster and anyone new to dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is that you need to make sure you're creating a new dictionary rather than modifying the original dictionary in `A`.  Here's a way to do it with `zip`:

```
B = [{**a, **c} for a, c in zip(A*2, [{'c': v} for v in L])]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you have to copy a dictionary because the variable it is stored to is an object, therefore modifying the object will affect all locations it appears.

```
a = {'a': 'example'}
B = [a]

#B[0] is a, so modifying a, also updates B[0]
a['a'] = 'test'
print(a)    #{'a': 'test'}
print(B[0]) #{'a': 'test'}
```

I'd like to point out the update function as a possibility.
The update function basically updates the existing dictionary by adding new keys to it from a source dictionary.

Example:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
c = {'c': 3}

a.update(c) #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Applying it to your code:

```
A={'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
L=['x', 'y']

import copy
B = []
for j in L:
  mod_info = {'c': j}
  A.update(mod_info)
  B.append(copy.copy(A))
print(B)
```